# How to filter content in Views based on multiple term custom fields?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to find a way to filter Views through contextual filters based on custom taxonomy term fields. Here is an example:

```
Content type: Article
Taxonomy vocabulary: Tags
Tags custom field: UniqueString
```

When I create an article, I assign tags to it. To every tag (taxonomy term) I assign an unique string. Example:

```
Article title: John Smith's best songs
Tags: John | Guitar
UniqueString for tag John: uid1
UniqueString for tag Guitar: uid2
```

Now I want to display articles that are tagged with both `John` and `Guitar`. This works:

```
Contextual filters:

Content: Has taxonomy term ID
Content: Has taxonomy term ID

View page path: views/taggedby/%/%
```

Path `views/taggedby/john/guitar` will display:

```
John Smith's best songs
```

However, I want to filter based on UniqueString value and not on tag names:

```
Relationships:

Content: Taxonomy terms on node

Contextual filters:

(term) Taxonomy term: UniqueString
(term) Taxonomy term: UniqueString

View page path: views/taggedby2/%/%
```

Path `views/taggedby2/john/guitar` will display an empty view. What's confusing is that everything works when there is only one filter and the path is `views/taggedby2/%`, so there has to be a way to make it work with multiple filters as well. E. g. if I change View page path to `views/taggedby2/%` and use `guitar` as an argument, it will display:

```
John Smith's best songs
```

How to make it work with two (or more) arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found a solution - it's necessary to add another relationship for the same field :

```
Content: Taxonomy terms on node, Identifier: term
Content: Taxonomy terms on node, Identifier: term2
```

The second contextual filter should use the second relationship (term2) and then everything works as expected.